# Designing application model API

Tags: java, api

What are the best practices of designing API for your application model?  Application should be separated as much as possible from user interface through such API.

Comment: If you have an object model and are writing an api to poke it, how would a user interface even be involved? Or are you asking about making an api to control your application?

Comment: Hello, yes I'm asking abound API that will control my application. I'm interested of other people general approaches.

Comment: Do you need to drive it in the same manner a user would (for testing), or are you trying to automate/script it for power users?

Comment: I need to drive it same as user for testing/changing UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a sort of MVC pattern for your application. I don't know are the namings same in the Java world, you have MVP / MVVM patterns at your disposal.

Of course, this is just for presentation part, you must take into account the size and needs of your application, so you can have service layers, database layers, network layers etc...

Check out Fowlers Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, check Domain Driven Development, check Onion architecture. It is a lot, but gives you some directions.

Comment: Hello, thank for you answer. I know about MVC pattern. I'm generally looking for some hints how to design interface to whole model (application core). Then it can be easily separated from view and controller.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is what is usually called Service Facade, but this is only viable in two cases: very complex domain logic involving, or distribution (network) layer in which your facade has coarse methods opposed to fine grained methods in your business layer (to minimize the number of needed calls that span network boundaries).